# Earphone behave strangely? Need to replug or use overamplification :(

Tags: sound, headphones

Laptop: Dell Inspiron 14 2-in-1
Earphone: Samsung AKG Type-C
Ubuntu: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (jammy)

Scenario 1: When I plug in the earphones, the sound switches from the laptop speaker to the earphones smoothly and the sound works fine in the earphones.

Scenario 2: Earphone is plugged in and when the device is not playing media for a few moments, there is no sound in the earphone if some media is played again. Then I have to unplug and re-plug in the earphones to get the sound back

Scenario 3: If I open the Sounds settings, under the output section: assuming that the earphone is just plugged in and sound is available in the earphone, if I switch to the laptop speaker, it switches smoothly. Sound is played from the laptop speaker. But if I switch back to the earphones being connected, there is now no sound in the earphones

Under every scenario when the sound goes away from the earphones, If I turn the overamplification feature `on` for the sounds from the Ubuntu sounds settings, and make the volume more than 100%, the earphone starts playing, but no sound below 100%.

What might be the issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: I suspect a hardware problem: an intermittent ground conbection ar the plug. Test by wiggling the cable at the plug.

Comment: It works very fine with my phone.